# How to reload a maxima file with a shortcut?

Tags: maxima

**First approach:**
I have something like below in my maxima init file (`maxima-init.mac').

```
load(my_maxima_functions);
c:load(my_maxima_functions);
```

When I make some change into `my_maxima_function` I do `c;`
An output like below appears:

`C:/pathto/my_maxima_functions.mac`
But the changes are not taken into account.

**Second approach:**
If I simply invoke
`load(my_maxima_functions);`
the new changes are taken into account.

What is wrong with the first approach?

Answer (score 0):

In Maxima, "code = data". That is, it's possible to represent code as data, and work with that code as if it were any kind of data.

What you want, I think, is

```
c: '(load ("my_functions.mac"));
```

which constructs an expression `load("my_functions.mac")` and assigns that expression to `c`. Then to execute the code you can say

```
ev(c);
```

and at that point `my_functions.mac` will actually get loaded.

Note the single quote mark in `c: '(load(...))`. The quote prevents evaluation of the stuff in `(load(...))`.

When you said `c: load(...)` originally, `load` was called and the file was loaded, and the file name returned. `c: '(load(...))` preserves `load(...)` as an unevaluated expression.